# How do you filter buffer list in a script?

Tags: buffers, list, filtering

Let's say there are three buffers:
"buffer1.py"
"buffer2.rb"
"buffer3.ipynb"

How do you filter/glob that list to select a specific buffer aka
`(switch-to-buffer "*.ipynb")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since it turns out you want to do this in a script you’ll have to do a little programming yourself. You can’t just pass a glob to the `switch-to-buffer` function. As you can see from it’s documentation, it only takes a buffer object or a buffer name as an argument.

Try something like this:

```lisp
(cl-find-if (lambda (b)
              (string-match-p "\\.ipynb$"
                              (buffer-name b)))
            (buffer-list))
```

This finds the first item in the `buffer-list` for which the predicate returns `t`. The predicate is a function that uses a regex to find buffer names that end with the string ".ipynb". Don’t forget to use `C-h f` to look up the documentation of any function that is unfamiliar to you.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much and sorry again for the confusing question.

Comment: You wouldn't also know by any chance if there is an equivalent `cl-find-if` function that would return ALL matches (not only the first one)?

Comment: Sure, just use `cl-remove-if-not`. It takes the same arguments.

Comment: Perfect, thank you again :) I may be pushing it too much now, but if you could also let me know how to check if two string-match-p functions are both true: ```(string-match-p "ein" (buffer-name b) (string-match-p "ipynb" (buffer-name b)``` one after the other (an 'and' keyword in python) that would be really helpful.

Comment: The `and` function is frequently useful. You should look that kind of thing up in the Emacs Lisp manual. Use `C-h i` to open the list of manuals installed on your computer.

Comment: thanks, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Put `(ido-mode t)` in your init file.

Now you have fuzzy matching in all your input prompts, so you when you do `C-x b` to switch buffers you can type "ipynb" and it will filter the list to only those with "ipynb" in the name.

Comment: Thanks, but it's meant to be used in a script, not interactively. Is it necessary to require an entire package just for this purpose? I thought that you could somehow check if there is an "ipynb" string in buffer-list variable?

Comment: You should make your question more clear then. No, there’s no built–in way to do that. Walk down the buffer list and compare the names against a regex.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here.